# Point Laravel Project Folder into existing server in nginx

Tags: laravel, git, nginx

I have pulled a new laravel project folder in staging server. The main project is existing from different project folder.

What I need to do is when user access an url https://my-domain/my-another-project-folder, it will point to my newly pulled project.

I have these environments running in nginx.

How will I able to achieve this?

I have pulled the new project folder in the server with my main project folder

1. main-project-folder
2. new-project-folder

Do i need to setup the routes in my main project pointing to new project? This is more of a server configuration